# UDP sockets with Python

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am trying to make a server capable of receiving and sending data using udp, I have reviewed some codes but they send or receive data, but not both, I am trying to send the data through one port and receive it by another, however I could not.

Had I thought about using the accept () function as in TCP, is there a similar way in UDP or a better solution? Thank you

```
while True:                                                 
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
  sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT1))
  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
  print data
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're a UDP listener, you `bind` a port to the socket.  If you are sender, you don't need to bind a port:

**echo server**

```
from socket import *

s = socket(type=SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('localhost',5000))

while True:
    data,addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    print(data,addr)
    s.sendto(data,addr)
```

**client**

```
from socket import *

s = socket(type=SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto(b'hello',('localhost',5000))
data,addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
print(data,addr)
```

Start the server then run the client.

**Client output:**

```
C:\>client.py
b'hello' ('127.0.0.1', 5000)

C:\>client.py
b'hello' ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
```

**Server output:**

```
C:\>server.py
b'hello' ('127.0.0.1', 50391)
b'hello' ('127.0.0.1', 50392)
```

Answer (score 0):

`accept()` is a TCP-only function, it has no application in UDP networking, so don't bother with it unless you are trying to use TCP.

As for sending data from one port while receiving it from another, the simple way to do that is to create two UDP sockets.  You can then call `recvfrom()` on one of them and `sendto()` on the other one.